# Spring Security Remember me with Basic Http Authentication

Tags: java, spring, security, basic-authentication, remember-me

In my Spring Boot backend server that serves an SPA (Angular), I use basic http authentication and once authenticated I get a session cookie that can be used to access the user even after closing the browser - which I understand is the purpose of `rememberMe()` but I never set it explicitly.

Here's my configuration:

```java
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic();
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/api/v1/version")
      .permitAll();
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(
        "/api/v1/auth/check", // API for checking if logged in
        "/api/v1/auth/login"  // used with Basic authentication header
      )
      .authenticated();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }
```

the store-type is mongodb:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-session-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

As you can see `rememberMe()` is not defined anywhere; Does that mean that it's running by default? or is it not relevant to how I handle things? I could use a proper explanation for this.

Another question on this topic; How can I enforce an API to only be accessible with the correct credentials in the headers (Basic Http Authentication), even when the session is active? for example a change password API which needs both the current password and a new password.

Thanks

Comment: Change password functionality would need to be implemented in a controller (for which you first do a check yourself). And no this isn't the remember-me functionality but rather just a session cookie with a certain lifetime. As you are storing the session in a persistent storage it will still be alive later on.

Comment: @M.Deinum So you're saying that if I move to local cookie storage then it won't remember the user and I'll have to explicitly call `rememberMe()`? I find it weird that simply changing the storage type affects this.

Comment: No that isn't what I'm saying. The session cookie will remain on the client, as long as the session is valid (and that depends on your configuration) it is available. That has nothing to do with remember-me.

Comment: @M.Deinum So what functionality does remember-me provide? Is it just the ability to *not* remember (as the default is to remember)?

Comment: You are confusing a session cookie (or session state) with a remember me functionality. Although similar they serve different purposes.